# Matlab Simulink: Summing up values only on specified points in time

Tags: matlab, simulink

From this signal I need to sum up the values, which the signal has, on multiples of 10. Basically the peaks at 10s, 20s, .... and so on.

How can I accomplish this in Simulink?

Signal with peaks marked in red:

[image: signal with peaks marked in red]

This signal is the result of a integrator, that gets a reset every 10s by a stair function. But I somehow can not figure out a way to connect the stair function to a switch block, that passes either a zero or the peak, because the conditions to trigger the switch are too unclear for the problem. I could use a repetitive ramp for this, but I fail to implement the repetitive ramp. But I am open to other solutions as well.

Comment: for the first part, i would use a matlab function block with findpeaks() inside. For the second part, you really need to share a picture for us to understand what is going on

Comment: you can find the picture in the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRPUq.png, it is in the post above too

Comment: the picture of the simulink diagram with blocks, not the signal one

Comment: I think this would make the question too specific. However I came to a solution myself in the meantime by using a matlab function block. As I know, that the integrator receives a reset every 10 seconds, in the matlab function block I apply the modulo operator on the time signal. If it is zero, the delayed signal from above has the peak values I need. It does work however I would rather have a block-based solution, as matlab functions slow down the simulation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.